# Retaining <li> tag with custom CSS links

Tags: jquery, mobile, html-lists

I have a been able to successfully integrate custom `<style>` classes into a jQuery Mobile CSS file I'm hosting myself and getting these to show up within a `<div data-role="collapsible">` list.

Example: http://www.camavision.com/wp/illinois/

However, using the `<li>` tag with these custom links kills the full bar mouseover effect that I was still hoping to retain where the whole area is linked instead of only the text.

I've added an example under the "A" category with the link labeled "Link Example without Style class applied" of what I'm trying to accomplish with a specific `<style>` link class still applied with a specific color.

Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Make a simple example - show us here the css, html and javascript (if any) that highlight your problem.  Giving us a URL in this instance is pointless due to the amount of messing about with the DOM that jQuery Mobile does.

Comment: Can you make it work though, to demonstrate the problem?  It will be a lot easier for people to help you if there's an isolated example that we can play with.

Comment: Here is the updated active link that you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/E3yaL/

Comment: You can't add `span` tags around the links - you're breaking jQuery Mobile by doing that.  This has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: Any suggestions to retain specific color links with javascript to retain the <li> tag style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were adding spans to the layout, in order to style elements within them, but this was breaking jQuery Mobile which expects a specific type of layout.  You just need to style the elements that are there, without adding anything.

To change the colour of the text in the li, add a class to the anchor tag and specify the colour in your stylesheet - use !important

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#" class="purple-link">Link Example without purple text</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
.purple-link
{
    color: purple !important;
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/E3yaL/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Completely fixes my problem. Appreciate it!